# Как в Visual Studio Community посмотреть историю в гите для выделенной строчки?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

В Rider есть классная фича: выделяем строчку -> правой кнопкой на нее -> git -> show hostory for current selection (или что-то в этом духе). Открывается окошко, в котором сразу видно, кто добавил данную строчку, когда добавил и тд. А можно так в студии?